# maven dependencies not found. showing errors in version

Tags: pom.xml, apache-kafka-streams

i am trying to include kafka streams dependencies in pom.xml and i m using intelij idea tool.. but those dependencies are showing errors as not found. It is showing errors in kafka streams, slf4j api and slf4j log4j12 dependencies..so can anyone help what might be the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.intel.clamp.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>streams-starter-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!--project dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--for logging purposes-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

so what might be the problem with my pom.xml?

Comment: Your `pom.xml` works fine in me. Did you reimport your changes or you may want to enable auto import in intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did `mvn clean install -U` in my project directory which worked fine for me..thank you!!